# Stack overflow error delphi 7

Tags: delphi, stack-overflow

I made application which has about 40 listboxes. I have infinite for loop that all the time ADD, DELETE or CHANGE items in these listboxes. after some time about 2 hours of ADDING, CHANGING and DELETING items i get "stack overflow" error message and application stops. I read on the internet it is something with memory. I have seen in the task manager that number of memory usage of my application is just growing and growing, but it never reduces. I think that my application never free the memory, so it is the problem. But i cant free listbox, because when i free listbox it dissapears. I didn't find any solution on the internet. Sorry for bad English, i think you can understand me. Thank you.

This example code is causing "Stack Overflow" error.
[Picture](http://postimg.org/image/9n931un3f/)

```
procedure TForm1.BeginLoopClick(Sender: TObject); //begin the process
var
i,p:integer;
s:string;
begin
  listbox1.Clear;
  for i:= 1 to 10 do
  begin
  listbox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(i));

      if i= 7 then
      begin
      listbox1.Items[0]:='5';
      listbox1.Items.Delete(6);
      listbox1.Items.Delete(5);
      listbox1.Items.Delete(4);
      listbox1.Items.Delete(3);

      CallBeginLoopClick(sender);
      end;

  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CallBeginLoopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
      BeginLoopClick(sender);
end;
```

Comment: You need to show us your code if you want help.

Comment: What does the debugger say? It should show you the stack.
In general, I'd avoid having an infinite loop in GUI (you just hang the application unless you're calling Application.ProcessMessages, and Application.ProcessMessages can call anything). Using a timer might be a better idea.

Comment: Don't rely on what Task Manager says, it is most likely misleading you.  Get yourself a copy of the FastMM4 replacement memory manager for Delphi apps; that can tell you whether your app is correctly freeing memory, etc.  When you get the stack overflow, in the IDE go to View | Debug Windows | Call stack - this should show what it is that's causing it.

Comment: Stack overflow almost certainly means recursion run wild.  If it's not that you allocated something huge on the stack.  Repeatedly allocating and freeing items will not cause it.

Comment: Your code has a defect. Only you can see the code. Good luck.

Comment: *I think you can understand me.* Think again. Show code. Don't describe it.

Comment: This design sounds like a disaster waiting to happen (actually, it already happened...). Without seeing your code or understanding what you are trying to accomplish with such an implementation, I really can't grasp why you would need an infinite loop here. Modern GUI programming does not rely on infinite loops. This sort of operation should be event driven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's run your code in pseudo steps:

```
1. Clear content
2. Add items 0 - 6, with data '1' - '7'
3. Change item 0's data into '5'
4. Delete item 3 - 6
5. There are three items left: 0 - 2 with data '5', '2', '3'
6. Goto step 1.
```

The only conclusion you can make is that this code will run forever, because there is no escape:

```
1. Clear content
2. Add items 0 - 6, with data '1' - '7'
3. Change item 0's data into '5'
4. Delete item 3 - 6
5. There are three items left: 0 - 2 with data '5', '2', '3'
6. Clear content
7. Add items 0 - 6, with data '1' - '7'
8. Change item 0's data into '5'
9. Delete item 3 - 6
10. There are three items left: 0 - 2 with data '5', '2', '3'
11. Clear content
12. Add items 0 - 6, with data '1' - '7'
13. Change item 0's data into '5'
14. Delete item 3 - 6
15. There are three items left: 0 - 2 with data '5', '2', '3'
16. etc...
```

The step that is missing from these steps is the call to `BeginLoopClick`. The routine calls itself (via another rutine) which is called recursion. All those calls are being remembered, because none will end. That is why your stack overflows (possibly among others like Windows Listbox internals).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there any way to make the code last forever without conclusion?

Comment: No. Normally, "infinite" running should be done in a background thread, but that's not an option for you since you ask explicitly for the main thread. To make your current model run continuously, the routine must end. Your code could be rewritten into an event driven model for example. But why on earth would you want to do that? Your program will be unresponsive for its entire existance. Is this an academic question?

Comment: Thank you @NGLN, you helped me very much. I didn't know what is causing "stack overflow" error. I solved it using timer and i made infinite looP, it's working without any errors. Thanks again!